# why plt.imshow(predict) shows a fully black image

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I set up a mechine learning model to predict a picture based on a given picture(using tensorflow). but when i use matplotlib, and use pyplot.imshow(predict), the picture showed is all black while the predict data is not all zero.

i am a freshman in python.any information would help a lot.
[the predict data displayed by pycharm debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwfBX.png)

```
predict = model.predict(np.array(x)).reshape([512, 512, 3])*255

predict=predict[:,:,0]
# # predict=tf.argmax(predict,axis=2)
# with tf.Session() as sess:
#     predict=predict.eval()


predict = np.array(predict.astype('uint8'))
print(predict.dtype)

pyplot.figure(2)
pyplot.imshow(predict)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: and when i want to get one of the three dimensions,such as predict[: , : , 0 ], it can show the differnce between each positions.

Comment: You need to do a few things: firstly make sure you have the correct cmap for imshow(), if you only have one channel then you'll probably want cmap = "grays", secondly you need to make sure that you are outputting the correct dimensions. You'll want to check the documentation for that (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

Comment: i found the reason why it it all black.....all of data are nearly zero , so the contrast aren't too big to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

While plotting the image you can set the minimum and maximum value range for the imshow

```
pyplot.imshow(predict,vmin=0, vmax=255)
```